# C++ Array outputting address?

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I posted earlier for the first time and was able to almost complete this assignment. The program isn't giving an error, but I'm getting undesired results. The output appears to be outputting the array address instead of the data I input. Or at least I think it is based on my very very limited knowledge. Can anyone help guide me in how to fix this? I've been working on this all day and at this hour, I think I'm ready to throw in the towel. Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
// Amanda 
// SoccerPlayer.cpp : main project file.
// October 6, 2012
/* a. Design a SoccerPlayer class that includes three integer fields: a player's jersey     number,
number of goals, and number of assists. Overload extraction and insertion operators for    the class.
b. Include an operation>() function for the class. One SoccerPlayer is considered greater
than another if the sum of goals plus assists is greater.
c. Create an array of 11 SoccerPlayers, then use the > operator to find the player who  has the
greatest goals plus assists.*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;



class SoccerPlayer
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const SoccerPlayer&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, SoccerPlayer&);
private:
    int jerseyNum;
    int numGoals;
    int numAssists;
public:
    SoccerPlayer(int, int, int);
    int score;
    int operator>(SoccerPlayer&);
    void DisplayStar();

};

SoccerPlayer::SoccerPlayer(int jersey = 0, int goal = 0, int assist = 0)
{
    jerseyNum = jersey;
    numGoals = goal;
    numAssists = assist;
} 

void SoccerPlayer::DisplayStar()
{
    cout<<"Player Number: "<< jerseyNum <<endl;
    cout<<"Goals Scored:  "<< numGoals <<endl;
    cout<<"Assists Made:  "<< numAssists <<endl;
} 

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& player,  const SoccerPlayer& aPlayer)
{
    player << "Jersey #" << aPlayer.jerseyNum <<
        " Number of Goals " << aPlayer.numGoals << 
        " Number of Assists " << aPlayer.numAssists;
    return player;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inPlayer, SoccerPlayer& aPlayer)
{

    cout << "Please enter the jersey number: ";
    inPlayer >> aPlayer.jerseyNum;
    cout << "Please enter the number of goals: ";
    inPlayer >> aPlayer.numGoals;
    cout << "Please enter the number of assists: ";
    inPlayer >> aPlayer.numAssists;

    aPlayer.score=(aPlayer.numGoals) + (aPlayer.numAssists);



    return inPlayer;
}

int SoccerPlayer::operator>(SoccerPlayer& aPlayer)
{

    int total = 0;
    if (score > aPlayer.score)
        total = 1;
    return total;


}

int main()
{
const int sz = 11;
int x;

SoccerPlayer aPlayer[sz];

for(x = 0; x < sz; ++x)
cin >> aPlayer[x];

{
 double max = aPlayer[x].score; 
 for(int i = 1; i<sz; ++i)
 {
     if(aPlayer[i] > aPlayer[x])
     {
         max=aPlayer[i].score;
     }

  }
 cout << max << endl;
 cout << aPlayer[x];
}
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only thing I have to offer at the moment is that you should eliminate as much irrelevant code as possible.

Comment: Testing this out, it appears to be large numbers, not addresses.

Comment: If x is intended to represent the index of the maximum scoring player in the second for loop, it should be initialized to zero before the loop begins and updated within the 'if(player[i] > ...)' block.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you intended a loop here, but it's malformed:

```
for(x = 0; x < sz; ++x)
cin >> aPlayer[x];

{
 double max = aPlayer[x].score; 
 for(int i = 1; i<sz; ++i)
 {
     if(aPlayer[i] > aPlayer[x])
     {
         max=aPlayer[i].score;
     }

  }
 cout << max << endl;
 cout << aPlayer[x];
}
```

You meant (I think) that `double max ...` should be inside the loop, but the `cin >> ...` line comes *after* the `for` statement, *outside* the braces. So the iteration applies only to the `cin >> ...` statement; once it's done, control proceeds to `double max = aPlayer[x].score;`, but x (left over from `for(...)`) is equal to `sz`, so `aPlayer[x]` is outside the array, in no-man's-land.

Put the `cin >> ...` inside the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only print the element `aPlayer[x]`. But notice that your first for loop terminates when `x = 11`. Well, that's one past the end of the array, so really, you're outputting junk.

I just tried it out with `aPlayer[0]` instead and got expected results.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with. Thanks everyone for the help!

```
// Amanda 
// SoccerPlayer.cpp : main project file.
// October 6, 2012
/* a. Design a SoccerPlayer class that includes three integer fields: a player's jersey number,
number of goals, and number of assists. Overload extraction and insertion operators for  the class.
b. Include an operation>() function for the class. One SoccerPlayer is considered greater
than another if the sum of goals plus assists is greater.
c. Create an array of 11 SoccerPlayers, then use the > operator to find the player who has the
greatest goals plus assists.*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;



//soccer player class - see above description
class SoccerPlayer
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const SoccerPlayer&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, SoccerPlayer&);
private:
    int jerseyNum;
    int numGoals;
    int numAssists;
public:
    SoccerPlayer(int, int, int);
    int score;
    int operator>(SoccerPlayer&);
    void DisplayStar();

};

//soccerplayer constructor
SoccerPlayer::SoccerPlayer(int jersey = 0, int goal = 0, int assist = 0)
{
    jerseyNum = jersey;
    numGoals = goal;
    numAssists = assist;
}
//to display star player
void SoccerPlayer::DisplayStar()
{
    cout<<"Jersey #: "<< jerseyNum <<endl;
    cout<<"Goals Scored:  "<< numGoals <<endl;
    cout<<"Assists Made:  "<< numAssists <<endl;
} 

//overload operator out
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& player,  const SoccerPlayer& aPlayer)
{
    player << "Jersey #" << aPlayer.jerseyNum <<
        " Number of Goals " << aPlayer.numGoals << 
        " Number of Assists " << aPlayer.numAssists;
    return player;
} 
//overload operator in
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inPlayer, SoccerPlayer& aPlayer)
{

    cout << "Please enter the jersey number: ";
    inPlayer >> aPlayer.jerseyNum;
    cout << "Please enter the number of goals: ";
    inPlayer >> aPlayer.numGoals;
    cout << "Please enter the number of assists: ";
    inPlayer >> aPlayer.numAssists;

    aPlayer.score=(aPlayer.numGoals) + (aPlayer.numAssists);
    return inPlayer;
} 

//overload operator greater than
int SoccerPlayer::operator>(SoccerPlayer& aPlayer)
{
    int total = 0;
    if (score > aPlayer.score)
        total = 1;
    return total;
}
//main declaration
int main()
{
    //11 players
    const int sz = 11;
    int x;
    SoccerPlayer aPlayer[sz];
    double max = 0;
    //to display star
    SoccerPlayer Star;
//allow user to input players, show what they input
for(x = 0; x < sz; ++x)
{
    cin >> aPlayer[x];
    cout << aPlayer[x] << endl << endl;
    for(int i=1; i<sz; i++)
    {
        Star=aPlayer[0];
        if(aPlayer[i] > aPlayer[i+1])

            Star=aPlayer[i];

    }
} 
//show star player
cout << "The Star Player: "<< endl;
Star.DisplayStar();
_getch();
return 0;
}
```